# How to put variable to img src path in Spring with thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Well, I want my image show up with table data at Front(html).
I use model.addAttributes to pass players information.
And my original imgfile is in path : /img/

This is my problem code below :

```
<tbody>
      <tr th:each="players : ${players}">
        <td><img src="/img/ + ${players.id} + '_' + ${players.name} + '.png'" width="120"/></td>
```

My image naming is always define with "id+name".png.
I don't know how to combine it to img src path.
And What I want for solution is to working like below :

```
        <td><img src="/img/1_pogba.png" width="120"/></td>
```

Comment: Have you tried src=\`/img/${players.id}_${players.name}.png\` (with backquote) ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use `th:src` with `img` tag instead of normal `src` attribute.
Just change your img tag from this:

```
<img src="/img/ + ${players.id} + '_' + ${players.name} + '.png'" width="120"/>
```

To this:

```
<img th:src="@{${'/img/' + players.id +'_'+ players.name + '.png'}}" width="120"/>
```

For more information you can check this link:

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html

Comment: I would recommend an expression like this: `th:src="@{/img/{id}_{name}.png(id=${players.id},name=${players.name})}"`