# How can i add an absolute image url in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

how can I add an online image url in thymeleaf like we do in html eg:

```
<img src="http://blahblah.png">
```

I want to add this "http://blahblah.png" dynamically i.e. I want to add this from database using a **controller** and **thymeleaf** inside **src**.

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63683474/how-to-put-variable-to-img-src-path-in-spring-with-thymeleaf

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, add the url to the model.

```
@Controller
public class ExampleController {

  @GetMapping("page")
  public String examplePage(Map<String, Object> model) {
    model.put("url", "https://google.com");
    return "page";
  }
}
```

On your page, set the value using `th:src`.

```
<img th:src="${url}" />
```